# hibernate mapping - Could not find a setter for property name in class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I find that hibernate need setter & getter with same/compatible name like:
`getName()` &  `setName()`

When setter looks like this `setblablaName ()`
Hibernate throws exception:
`org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter for property name in class`
When I add setter with compatible getter name (setName())  -  It’s solved.

But it’s seems a lot of work & risk to make those changes in all the code..
I look for an alternative solution for this issue..

note (i mapping the class with annotation)

Comment: Use IDE's feature to generate setter/getter

Answer (score 2):

learn about the javabean spec.

For a property of  `blablaName` you would need a

```
 setBlablaName (...)
```

Modern IDEs have wizards for generating setters/getters

Answer (score 0):

You could generate setters and getters with your IDE look for

```
source>generate getters and setters
```

then select the variables you want to have setters and getters.another way is to right click to your coding area then look for source>generate getters and setters, this will save a lot of time :)

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to change setter method name, then you can use a delegate method

```
setblablaName(arg){
  setName(arg);
}
```

put your hibernate annotation on setName() & getName()